# How to load related entities with the Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am exploring with Entity Framework Core and started off by using the code first approach while reading through this guide https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html with the exception of different models.

In EF6 it had lazy loading and I was able to pull the related entities really easily but it is no working in EF Core. I was wondering how to get this working or if there is a work around to get it working.

Here is an example of what Two of my models look like:

```
public class Team
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public string Mascot { get; set; }
    public string Conference { get; set; }
    public int NationalRank { get; set; }

    public List<Game> Games { get; set; }
}

public class Game
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Opponent { get; set; }
    public string OpponentLogo { get; set; }
    public string GameDate { get; set; }
    public string GameTime { get; set; }
    public string TvNetwork { get; set; }
    public string TeamId { get; set; }

    public Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

I am wanting to get all of the Games for a Team but as of right now it is null.

I decided to make a Web Api project so I have a controller called TeamsController and when I make a GET request to the controller I want to get a list of Teams with the Games property populated with the related games.

Here is what I have tried:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<List<Team>> Get()
{
    return await _context.Teams.Include(t => t.Games).ToListAsync();
}
```

This is the JSON result:

```
[
  {
    "id": "007b4f09-d4da-4040-be3a-8e45fc0a572b",
    "name": "New Mexico",
    "icon": "lobos.jpg",
    "mascot": "New Mexico Lobos",
    "conference": "MW - Mountain",
    "nationalRank": null,
    "games": [
      {
        "id": "1198e6b1-e8ab-48ab-a63f-e86421126361",
        "opponent": "vs Air Force*",
        "opponentLogo": "falcons.jpg",
        "gameDate": "Sat, Oct 15",
        "gameTime": "TBD ",
        "tvNetwork": null,
        "teamId": "007b4f09-d4da-4040-be3a-8e45fc0a572b"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

When I do this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<List<Team>> Get()
{
    return await _context.Teams.ToListAsync();
}
```

I get all of the teams but the Games property is null.

I was hoping it would return all the teams in the database along with all of the games for each team. How can I get this working?

Comment: According to [this](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/related-data.html), lazy loading is not implemented yet.

Comment: Also be aware that lazy loading can cause performance issues, depending on how many teams you will have. With lazy loading you would have `1+n = <calls to database>` where `n` is the number of teams in the database.

Comment: @Michael Under the Eager Loading section of the article it says you are able to use the .Include() which I have tried but for some reason it is only returning the first team and the first game of the first team. Like it show in the json output. Do you happen to know why it isn't getting all of the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lazy loading is currently not implemented in entity framework core as [indicated here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3797),  I suggest you to look at AutoMapper to project your desired results in POCO. Because what you want will exactly cause the n+1 problem.